# When using float64 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, floating-point

```
      2 z = 1
      3 while z!=0:
      4         n+=1
----> 5         z=float64(y)**(-n)
      6 return n
      7 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Convert `y` to a float? Are you using the `float64` module from numpy?